# RIA Services and EF validation

Tags: entity-framework, validation, metadata, wcf-ria-services

I'm developing a Silverlight application with Entity Framework and RIA Services. When I create the RIA Service I have the option to generate a metadata class for basic validation.

What is the difference between the validation I can do directly with EF and the one in the metadata class generated with RIA service? I mean, if I have a property in the EF model which is not null, I don't need to mark it in the metadata class as [Required]... Is it because this is already done by the EF model??

THANKS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the metadata classes you can add more validation logic to your entities. See the namespace [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx) for more details. EF currently only supportes the Required attribute. The namespace provides more attributes, such as RangeAttribute, StringLength or custom attributes that you define for your own validation logic.

[Jeff Handly](http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2010/09/22/RiaServicesStandardValidators.aspx) has a good series of blog post, that describe the validation process and elements in WCF Ria Services.